# How do I find the expectation value given only the eigen energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Let $|n \rangle$ denote the $n^{th}$ stationary state of the harmonic oscillator, with energy 
$E_n = \hbar \omega(n+\frac{1}{2})$

How would I find $\langle x\rangle$ and $\sigma_x$

I know that

$$\langle x\rangle = \langle \alpha|x\alpha \rangle = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}\langle \alpha|(a_+ + a_-)\alpha \rangle=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}(\alpha + \alpha^*)$$

but that is just from the definition of ladder operator, what does it have to do with energy eigenstate?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are attempting to determine $\langle n|x|n\rangle$, you're on the right track.  Here are some

Hints:

1. Determine what the ladder operators do the the energy eigenstates;
   \begin{align}
     a|n\rangle = ?, \qquad a^\dagger |n\rangle = ?
   \end{align}
2. Write the position operator in terms of ladder operators as you have done.
3. What are the inner products of the energy eigenstates:
   \begin{align}
     \langle m|n\rangle = ?
   \end{align}
4. Combine this all together to obtain the desired expressions for $\langle x\rangle = \langle n|x|n\rangle$.